# How to remove the first three character from the fasta file header

Tags: linux, trim, cut

I have a fasta file like this:

```
>rna-XM_00001.1 
actact
>rna-XM_00002.1
atcatc
```

How do I remove the 'rna-' so it become

```
>XM_00001.1 
actact
>XM_00002.1
atcatc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're showing is the file contents? Then sed should be able to do this:

`sed 's/^>rna-/>/' < inputfile > outputfile`

Explanation:

- The first character of the command-line to sed is `s`, which tells sed to do substitution
- The `/` are delimiters
- The `^` tells sed to look only at the start of a line
- The next `>rna-` is the pattern to match at the start of a line
- The next `>` is the replacement substituted for the pattern

If, instead, you want to always remove the first four characters after a `>` as long as they end in `-`, you could use:

`sed 's/^>...-/>/' < inputfile > outputfile`

Explanation:

- This is similar to above, except the pattern to match at the start of a line is `>...-`. The pattern is a regexp, where a `.` matches any single character. So this pattern matches any line starting with `>`, followed by any three characters, followed by `-`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. It does the work.